# Indefinite Integral does not compute, antiderivative however does

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the function:

$ t = t_0 - \frac{\sqrt{a-1}}{c} \int_s^r \frac{dr'}{(1-\frac{s}{r'})\sqrt{\frac{a s}{r'}-1}}$

I am currently using $c=1$, $s=1$, $t_0=0$ and $a=2$ as an example for plotting. Therefore I get:
$t = -\int_2^r \frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{r}) \sqrt{\frac{2}{r}-1}}$

Ultimately, I am planning to plot x against t.

Mathematica gives me a result for the antiderivative if I give the input:

`t = Integrate[(-(Sqrt[a - 1]/c))*(1/((1 - s/r)*Sqrt[a*(s/r) - 1])), r]`

However if I take the indefinite integral as input:

`t= Integrate[-1/((1-1/r)*Sqrt[2/r-1]),{r,2,R}]`

I get the input as the output.

Now as you can probably see from the equation, inserting the lower value won't really do the job.

This is how the plot of the antiderivative looks like:
[image: Plot of antiderivative]

It is supposed to be the same, but with an offset on the y axis.

Do you have any ideas how to get an expression for t? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you say is working and not working? Thanks

Comment: This works:
`t = Integrate[(-(Sqrt[a - 1]/c))*(1/((1 - s/r)*Sqrt[a*(s/r) - 1])), r]`
However, if I try:
`t= Integrate[1/((1-1/r)*Sqrt[2/r-1]),{r,2,R}]`
I just get the input as output

Comment: Apparently the indefinite integral can be computed but not the definite one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possibilities:

```
Integrate[1/((1 - 1/r)*Sqrt[2/r - 1]), {r, 2, R}, Assumptions -> R > 2]

(* -I (Sqrt[(-2 + R) R] + ArcTan[(-2 + Sqrt[R])/Sqrt[-2 + R]] +
    ArcTan[(2 + Sqrt[R])/Sqrt[-2 + R]] - Log[4] + 
   4 Log[Sqrt[-2 + R] + Sqrt[R]]) *)

f[bigR_?NumericQ] := 
  Integrate[1/((1 - 1/r)*Sqrt[2/r - 1]), {r, 2, bigR}]
f[3]

(* -I (Sqrt[3] + π/3 + Log[7 + 4 Sqrt[3]]) *)

f2[bigR_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[1/((1 - 1/r)*Sqrt[2/r - 1]), {r, 2, bigR}]
f2[3]

(* 0. - 5.41316415262 I *)
```

All three agree when that upper bound is set to 3.

Comment: I just tried your first method with `Assumptions -> 1 < R < 2` and it works. Thank you!